# The usage of "exploding" in "their batteries exploding"

Tags: verb-usage

The following is an excerpt from WSJ:

> The world’s largest smartphone maker by shipments said it halted sales of its Galaxy Note 7 phone after customers reported **their batteries *exploding*** during charging.

[Source](http://www.wsj.com/articles/samsung-to-recall-galaxy-note-7-smartphone-1472805076)

I wonders how "their batteries exploding" is constructed. Would it be the same to say "their batteries explosion"? In English, sometimes it seems to use a "Verb -ing" form instead of a noun form.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Two words are elided from the phrase: _customers reported **that** their batteries **were** exploding._ In _journalese,_ this kind of [tag:ellipsis] is not uncommon. The reason that English seems to use a **verb-ing** form of a verb sometimes is that it **is** the **noun form** of the verb. This is the [tag:gerund]. (_"Their batteries explosion"_ is meaningless in English because there is no [tag:verb] present.)

Comment: Thank *you* for including a link to your source (the WSJ). You also ask a very specific question, and ask about an alternative construction. All in all, this could be a model question for all learners to learn from.

Comment: I can't really add much to what @P.E.Dant has said in his comment. It's probably good enough to be a short answer. I am not 100% sure we have to say it is ellipsis, or whether it is just extremely helpful to consider it as ellipsis.

Comment: @AlanCarmack You are correct; I was going for helpful. Analyses of journalese are often rabbit holes, in my experience.

Comment: @P.E.Dant : Why do you not post your comment as an Answer? It might be considered "short" but it addresses the question comprehensively. It is far more than a comment.

Comment: I'm not confident about ellipsis here. It's journalese, too, which makes me chary. Alan's right about the question being an exemplar of good construction, but I don't see what "Thank you in advance" adds to it. I've removed it once, and Alan decided it was a valuable component of the question and added it back, so I'll let someone else take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of (transitive) **reported** is a nominal of some kind or a *that*-clause. The complement must answer to "reported what?" They reported "something".

Consumers reported

> their lettuce wilting | that their lettuce wilted | the wilting of their lettuce
>
> their batteries exploding  | that their batteries exploded | the explosion of their batteries
>
> having gas after eating beans | that they had gas after eating beans | their gas after eating beans

The noun-from-verb **wilting|exploding** doubles as a nominal and as a verb. It satisfies both the "reported what?" and the "did what?" question.

What did the lettuce do? It wilted.

What did the batteries do? They exploded.

The difference is finite/non-finite. Nominals are non-finite or a-finite.